# Configuring GitHub hooks to call an end-point that is OAuth protected

Tags: git, api, github, webhooks

I have an API that is wrapped around a very simple OAuth implementation. This API has an end-point which when called with the correct data performs a git pull operation on a repository configured on the server on which the end-point is running. My goal is to configure a web-hook on GitHub (or BitBucket) that should work such that every time there is a push to the repository, that end-point on my server is called to pull the latest changes on the copy of the repository on my server.

However, as far as I have looked at the documentation for GitHub web-hooks, I have not been able to found support for anything beyond a direct callback URL. How would I go about implementing something like this? Would setting up an intermediary end-point that in turn calls the API be cleaner approach?

Many thanks.